# Elemento footer não descem usando a class bootstrap quando abro o menu em modo mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Em modo mobile está com problemas quando abro o menu pois este colide com os botões de passar imagens do carousel e tambem com o footer

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CSS**

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: auto;
  background-color: #0275d8;
}
```

já tentei usar   z-index: -1;

```
<div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
      <hr>
          <div id="aviso">  
            <div id= "posicaoaviso">
                <span id="fecharaviso" >&times;</span>
                <center><p><strong>Uso de cookies:</strong> Este site utiliza cookies para ajudar a disponibilizar os respetivos serviços e analisar o tráfego.<br>As informações sobre a sua utilização deste site são partilhadas com terceiros.<br>Ao utilizar este site, concorda que o mesmo utilize cookies.</p></center>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Clique [aqui](http://turismo.adota-me.tk/) para visualizar o site.

Ou o problema está no footer ou esta no carrosel

Comment: substitua: `width:100%` por `max-width:100%` Você gostaria que ele ficasse responsivo certo? Ele está dentro de um container e row?

Comment: Continua com problemas quando faço isso

Comment: Parece ser o elemento  class="carousel slide"    mas não entendo porque ele fica sobreposto com o class="footer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrigido desta forma

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 120px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```